# Powershell command to find registry key advanced audit settings (permissions)

Tags: powershell, registry, audit, powershell-ise, regedit

I am trying to use powershell commands to get the registry key advanced audit settings, after a while of testing I have managed to come to this point:

```
(Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).AuditToString
```

Using that command gives me no output (advanced audit settings are in place so I am expecting an output). It seems like I am very close with this command and I may be missing a parameter. I have been at this for a while with no luck so I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you get output from `Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`?  If so, I'd suggest piping it to `| Get-Member -m *Property` to make sure you're accessing the right member.

Comment: Running that gives me an output of the owner and access (Administrator) and I have opened the powershell as admin.

Comment: `Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion | gm audittostring | select -expand definition` Run this command and see what that function is doing.  If it can't find an audit member, it returns an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have an element "AdvancedAudit" at HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"

This is how you access it...Hope it helps!

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).AdvancedAudit
```